# Why no static indexers?

Tags: c#, static-indexers

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to reference an indexer member of a class in C# comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341118/how-to-reference-an-indexer-member-of-a-class-in-c-comments)
>   [Static Indexers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401232/static-indexers)

---

As it stands, I have to write my code like this

```
internal class ReportMap {

    static internal ReportMap Instance {
        get { return reportMap; }
    }

    internal Type this[char c] {
        get { return data[c]; }
    }

    // private parts
    static Dictionary<char, Type> data =
        new Dictionary<char, Type>();

    ReportMap() {
        data.Add('S', typeof(StatusReport));
        data.Add('Q', typeof(QualityReport));
    }

    static ReportMap reportMap = new ReportMap();
}
```

and to access an index:

```
Type t = ReportMap.Instance[aChar]; // eww
```

Is there a specific reason this ability was left out of the language?  In particular, would it be considered bad design?  There is another question on this already posted, but I unfortunately do not have enough rep to comment.

Comment: I think the question is answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401232/static-indexers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a good dupe reference there.  Specifically, check out the answer :-)
[Static Indexers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401232/static-indexers/401275#401275)