# What's the syntax to inherit documentation from another indexer?

Tags: c#, sandcastle, xml-documentation

In my implementation I have this:

```
/// <inheritdoc cref="IInterface{T} this[,]"/>
public T this[long row, long column]
{
    ...
}
```

The XMLdoc is already present in the `IInterface`. How can I pick it up from there (like I do for other things)?

I get a compiler warning:

> Warning   108 XML comment on 'XXX.YYY.this[long, long]' has syntactically incorrect cref attribute 'IInterface this[,]'

I tried removing the `this` from the `cref` but that didn't work either. What syntax do I need?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this:
`cref="IInterface{T}.this[long,long]"`