# XML comments cannot correctly reference properties named 'Item'

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, xml-comments

Given the following code:

```
class FixedWidthReader<T>
{
    public T? Item { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Populates <see cref="Item"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public void Run()
    {

    }
}
```

The XML comments do not show the reference to `Item` correctly.

[image]

If I rename the `Item` property to anything else, say `ItemX`, it works fine.

[image]

Does anyone know why XML comments cannot correctly refer to a property called `Item`?

Comment: It's also worth noting that this behavior also occurs if the class is not generic, and the property returned a fixed data type (such as string).

Answer (score 2):

Defining it as `<see cref="P:Item" />` shows

> Populates Item.

```
/// <summary>
/// Populates <see cref="P:Item" />.
/// </summary>
public void Run()
{

}
```

[image]

The ID Strings section in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/#id-strings) shows the available prefixes, but for some reason any prefix character seems to give the same result when looking at it in Visual Studio.
(*I'm using Visual Studio 2022.*)

Maybe the correct usage of these is more important when using a document generation tool like DocFX or Sandcastle.

The table shows character `P` for member type `Property`.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341118/how-to-reference-an-indexer-member-of-a-class-in-c-sharp-comments) shows more usages of these prefixes.

---

**Update**

When you configure Visual Studio to generate an XML documentation file in its output, you'll notice that also that `ItemX` property as in your example ends up as `` cref="P:FixedWidthReader`1.ItemX" ``.

```
<member name="M:FixedWidthReader`1.Run">
    <summary>
    Populates <see cref="P:FixedWidthReader`1.ItemX"/>.
    </summary>
</member>
```

That generic format `` FixedWidthReader`1 `` looks to be the expected output, but for some reason Visual Studio has an issue in visualizing such a property when named `Item`, like you're suspecting.

I tend to say that making that change towards `cref="P:Item"` will break the actual type definition, just affecting the Visual Studio visualization.

Comment: That's weird how the `P` prefix shows the right name but the name is not highlighted like normal property references. I'm pretty sure the issue I reported is confusing Visual Studio because of special handling for indexers.